# How to disable my inboard ( intel ) graphic card

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics, xorg, intel-graphics

I'm pretty new to linux, but I did my best to obtain all information regarding my issue so maybe someone could help out.

I have an HP Pavilion dv6 Notebook, with Ubuntu 14.04 manually installed.

The log of `lspci | grep VGA` is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 630M] (rev ff)
```

I need to disable the Intel graphic card and only use my NVIDIA, as currently I'm pretty sure the NVIDIA is not in use.

From `lsmod` I see it uses the i915 module. I tried blacklisting that module in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` but that didn't really work because i still couldn't use the NVIDIA card for display.

I can't enable NVIDIA from BIOS, nor disable intel.

So what I'm looking for is a solution allowing me to use the power of my NVIDIA laptop, as currently the graphics are pretty bad due to the intel usage.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do.

If you use the Driver Manager/Additional Drivers (Jockey) Utility and select the available nvidia driver. You can install the nvidia drivers properly.

Upon Reboot, you can use the Nvidia X Server configuration Utility(nvidia-settings) to Select. Either Performance Mode or Power saving Mode.

In the power saving mode only Intel Graphics Card stays Active and in the performance mode only Nvidia Card Stays active. By default once you Install the nvidia-drivers nvidia Card will stay active. Switching from One card to the other card does require you to logout and login again.

Since you only want to use the nvidia card You should be good after installing the drivers using the Additional Drivers utility (Jockey).

Please post here if this does not resolve your issue.

If you want to use the latest drivers for Nvidia card, Please use the ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

Note: Please stay away from nvidia-361 drivers as they have issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Once I do that, I get this http://i.imgur.com/LtK3z4F.png

Comment: This is my xorg.conf file:
http://i.imgur.com/q72fsfT.png

Comment: What happens when you click on OK? I would recommend that you remove nvidia and nvidia-prime completely and start fresh.. When you select a gpu it should ask you for a password every time you switch the GPU.